# TypeScript matching against Resulting type of String Literal Template

Tags: typescript, types

I have type:

```
type To_String<N extends number> = `${N}`
```

I create Type that maps resulting string number:

```
type Remap<Number>
    = Number extends '0'
    ? 'is zero'
    : Number extends '1'
    ? 'is one'
    : Number extends '2'
    ? 'is two'
    : 'other number'

type One = Remap<To_String<1>> // 'is one'
type Other = Remap<To_String<5>> // 'other number'
```

So far so good, but then I try to pass just 'number', as would be for instance attempt to call function returning 'number', and here I can't figure how to match against resulting type that shows in backticks and matches against string:

```
type Remap<Number>
    // = Number extends `${number}` - attempt that catches all values
    = Number extends '${number}' // not matched against string version
    ? 'is Template literal result'
    : Number extends '1'
    ? 'is one'
    : Number extends '2'
    ? 'is two'
    : 'other number'

// this gives result type enclosed in backticks that still passes as string
type Template_String_Result = To_String<number> // `${number}`
// attempt that fails to catch top match clause
type Non_Literal_Number = Remap<To_String<number>>
```

Is there any way to get match against this Template literal string?

Comment: I don't understand what the goal is here. What exact type do you want `Template_String_Result` and `Non_Literal_Number` to be? And is `To_String` doing what you want it to do when you use `To_String<number>`? If not, what do you want it to do?

Comment: Template_String_Result was just test type to show that it returns `${number}`
and Non_Literal_Number should result in 'is Template literal result', i just dont know how to match against it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to use `` ​`${number}` extends Number `` for your first condition, since `Number` is a generic parameter so it could be broader than `${number}` (although in your specific case it won't be). But if we put the test the other way around, that's fine, because anything matching `${number}` would also match something broader than `${number}`.

```
type Remap<Number>
    = `${number}` extends Number
    ? "is Template literal result"
    : Number extends "1"
    ? "is one"
    : Number extends "2"
    ? "is two"
    : "other number"
```

Then you get these results, which I think are what you're looking for:

```
type One = Remap<To_String<1>>
//   ^? type One = "is one"
type Two = Remap<To_String<2>>
//   ^? type Two = "is two"
type Other = Remap<To_String<5>>
//   ^? type Other = "other number"
type Non_Literal_Number = Remap<To_String<number>>
//   ^? type Non_Literal_Number = "is Template Literal result"
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gfQMrAE4EsB2BzAPAOSggA9gJMATAZykwFcBbAIwlQD4oBeKAAwBIA3vgC+PAFBjQkKACUIDAIZgCjFuzFRNXXoPrNWooqXLUo+Vaw1aA-FABE6GjHlgANgrJRX6MqgWuoVAgqOldgOytNAC4zC1QjMkoaOwBGCK0oWwcaOEwIdK0Y8314kkTTOwAmAs0sxyhgAHc4GqgYuzhgAAtWWjiIyXBoAHk87TlFZXhkNCw8FLY2MQB6Za0APWtB6Rhm8fklXGmUDBxcSsWVtc1N7ZHu3u4Jw+PZs4BWS9WNralofFyCAAMj5WP4EMU1PtJkdECc5rg9GovtcoLcgA)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I certainly don't understand that as well, but this solves it perfectly, thanks again.

Comment: @Jarek - My pleasure. The problem with not understanding it, of course, is that we don't know that it's defined behavior. So you'll want to be sure to double-check it each time you upgrade your TypeScript version, unless someone chimes in to explain what we're missing. :-)

Comment: @Jarek - Having looked into type compatibility of template literals further, I think we're fine above, it's intentional behavior. For `literalA extends literalB`, think of it this way: Would something matching `literalA` also match `literalB`? If so, that's true; if not, it's false. Experiments and reasoning [here](https://tsplay.dev/NDaa8m). :-)

Comment: This is useful, too bad it is hidden only as a link in comment :(

Comment: @Jarek - Do you think it would be useful in the answer? Seemed tangential to me, but I'm happy to edit if you think otherwise. :-) (I was actually thinking of posting it as a question...)

Comment: Yeah, either appendage here, or transforming it to question, it is helpful for some more understanding about this  not very documented thing

Comment: @Jarek - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78139614/when-does-a-template-literal-type-with-placeholders-extend-another-one :-)