# When does a template literal type with placeholders extend another one?

Tags: typescript, subtyping, template-literal-types

What is the subtype rule for template literal types with placeholders (like `` `${number}em` ``)? It's not covered by the [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#handbook-content) part of the handbook and I didn't find anything for it in searches though I could have missed it somewhere; it's tricky to search for.

I ask because I was surprised recently by `` `${number}` extends `${string}` `` being true. On reflection, I have a reasonable thought for why it is, but I'm looking either for confirmation and details if I'm right or the correct explanation if I'm wrong. (For context, this came up while I was trying to prove to myself that my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78116479/typescript-matching-against-resulting-type-of-string-literal-template) was reliable.)

My thought is:

- Template literal type `S` is a subtype of template literal type `T` if a string that would match `S` would also match `T`.

That's true for my `` `${number}` extends `${string}` `` example because any series of characters that would match `` `${number}` `` (like `"123"`) would also match `` `${string}` ``.

That also seems like a reasonable fit for [the general rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) that *"...any term of type `S` can safely be used in any context where a term of type `T` is expected..."*.

Is that correct and if so, is there further nuance? If not, what is the correct definition?

FWIW, here is my somewhat-meandering series of tests that I used to test my intuition:

```
type A = `${number}` extends `${number}` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// true, since they're the same thing, so yeah, it's a match

type B = `${number}` extends `${number|string}` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// true, anything matching `${number}` would also match `${number|string}`

type C = `${number}` extends `${string}` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// true, which makes sense for a template literal even though number isn't a subtype of
// string, because anything matching `${number}` would also match `${string}` --
// that is, a series of digits is not just a valid number, but also a valid string

type D = `${string}` extends `${number}` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// false, because the converse isn't true; not all sequences of characters are
// valid numbers

type E = `${number|string}` extends `${number}` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// false - same as D, basically

type F = `${number}` extends `${string}${number}` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// false because something matching `${number}` wouldn't match `${string}${number}`

type G = `${string}${number}` extends `${string}${number}` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// true, they're the same thing

type H = `${number}${string}` extends `${string}${number}` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// false, for the same reason as D and E

type I = `${number}x` extends `${string}x` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// true - basically the same as C, just with an x on it

type J = `${number}x` extends `${string}y` ? true : false;
//   ^?
// false because something matching `${number}x` wouldn't match `${string}y`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JlZp8G5Ve61RRPJp3SS0iD0xm2aCGdwYFGEIG4-GEipSPUGqZiMSKgCOfCMKopUEiIkIIkM1CzUxsTXNcKt3PobriAFFvXk0stzmLDlkTntg5dQ5U4w86jG6vOoOL7I4powPbSRPp6SWQL3oAAxQfYv1HbKnFZrINDGcVcPzqP1RrL6rQOkMoEeRxdNmzH0bJTvevJjBMuZCvMIo3sQd4HEeUAAOKDr68E8v6V4waOt5DgcnCzk+H4vkuGgtDoZgWNYKbrk4qyIQAEme3JwWgvrjgG144ax54PtctzEY8DTPIo846EIIJotA9AONANi7umm5QF67STH2iEAJLMcGFAcVhPqwbpBGPgJkZCW+ZFhmueC7p84hiCAUm0UpWw6MaxS8gE8ztFAFDkhgcrAIhABS2lDEZmGTgZ3EgHxYamTU5kiRGQJfsmujuH+rLOFBnJ4SQRl8hBBJQVxpSxTIQA)

Comment: The canonical answer to this is probably "as implemented in [ms/TS#43361](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43361)" Your tests touch a lot of different things so it's not obvious how to write a non-book-length answer. Generally speaking `A extends B` if a value of type `A` is assignable to a variable of type `B`, so the basic intuition you have is what I have also. (more...)

Comment: (...continued)  But template literals with placeholders (and note that a literal type or union of literal types is *not* a placeholder, so the enum stuff in your tests isn't really relevant) are weird in multiple ways, as per [ms/TS#57355](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57355) and [ms/TS#57404](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57404) so it's fiddly and not easy to explain in an SO answer. How would you like to proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz - Thanks, I was hoping you might see this. Definitely not worth writing a book-length answer for. :-) Perhaps an answer basically saying what you've said in the comments, slightly expanded? Am I right that the main take-aways are: 1. Your (rather more informed) intuition matches mine, details in #43361. 2. The enum tests are off-base because they aren't placeholders. (I have to admit I don't get that part. Maybe it's off-topic, but a brief explanation of what's really going on there would be good.) 3. Beware weird behaviors like the ones you've cited. Sound about right? TIA

Comment: If you write `type SE = \`${StringEnum}\`` and inspect it, you'll see `type SE = "a" | "b" | "c"`. That's not even a template literal type anymore, just a union of string literals.  The word "placeholder" implies that it holding a place for something to be filled in later.  String literal types where you interpolate types only result in placeholders if they are wide types like `string` and `number` or indeterminate like `infer S` in a conditional type.  Does that make sense? I'm not sure that's really relevant in the answer to this question though.

Comment: @jcalz - It does make sense, thanks. And yeah, it's tangential to the question. I've removed the enum tests, since they aren't testing what I thought they were testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignability of [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) with placeholders (with wide types like `string` as in `` `abc${string}ghi` `` or with indeterminate types like `infer U` as in `` T extends `abc${infer U}ghi` ? U : never ``) was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#43361](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43361).  So that's the  authoritative answer for how this works.

Conceptually, yes, `X extends Y` when every value of type `X` can be safely assigned to a variable of type `Y`. So your intuition is correct and explains most of what's going on.

---

Except that template literal types with placeholders don't always behave as some people expect.

For example, when two placeholders are next to each other, the first one matches exactly one character from the input. So `"a"` doesn't match `` `a${string}${string}` ``:

```
type Hmm = "a" extends `a${string}${string}` ? true : false
//   ^? type Hmm = false
```

But template literals consisting only of repeated `string` placeholders are collapsed to `string`, so  `""` *does* match `` `${string}${string}` ``. See [microsoft/TypeScript#57355](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57355).

```
type Wha = "" extends `${string}${string}` ? true : false
//   ^? type Wha = true
```

And a `number` placeholder doesn't refer to "those strings which are what you get when you serialize a `number` with a template literal string"; instead it refers to "anything which can be successfully parsed as a `number`", which also leads to weird behavior. See [microsoft/TypeScript#57404](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57404) and [this comment on a related issue microsoft/TypeScript#41893](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41893#issuecomment-889292665):

```
type Oops = "a       0" extends `a${number}` ? true : false
//   ^? type Oops = true
```

So while TypeScript does more or less follow the rule that "if `X` is assignable to `Y` then `X extends Y ? true : false` is `true`, sometimes it's not obvious when `X` is assignable to `Y`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEgtnKBeKAiAhqqEAewIB2AJgM5QAG6AJAN4nABOAlgQOYC+t9zb75UAfiiMArtABcUAGboANiQgAoAPTKo6gHpDQkWAmTS5CxYp3QA6gAt0B1Flz5iZcl0YsOrnh37aGYqJIy8kqq6lBawuAW1gaiSqZRUADyAPZgZCgYYdkADPZ4hKQU1DQEInAARhAMfILCfhKGwSpqmtqJqemxDUA)